# Laravel many many relation cannot get pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I have laravel's basic auth system, a custom model called SecurityQuestion and a pivot table called **securityquestion_user**

User

```
public function securityquestion_user() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(SecurityQuestion::class, 'securityquestion_user', 'question_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('question_id', 'user_id', 'answer');
}
```

SomeController

**First option**

```
foreach(Auth::user()->securityquestion_user as $question) {
    dd($question);
}
```

> Error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::$pivot

**Second Option**

```
foreach(Auth::user()->securityquestion_user() as $question) {
    dd($question);
}
```

> Error: returns false

Comment: Can you try like ->withPivot(['x','y','z']), -adding square brackets-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys I got it,

I modified the relation to this:

```
public function securityquestion_user() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SecurityQuestion', 'securityquestion_user', 'user_id', 'question_id')->withPivot('question_id', 'user_id', 'answer');
}
```

Basically I reversed the order and place 'user_id' parameter before 'question_id' parameter.

```
foreach(Auth::user()->securityquestion_user as $question) {
        print '<pre>';
        print_r($question->pivot->answer);
        print '</pre>';
    }
```

Thank you very much for you interest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added namespace for auth in controller? 
 Like:

```
use Auth;
```

If not imported then use this for it:

```
foreach(\Auth::user()->securityquestion_user as $question) {
    dd($question);
}
```

And also correct your function in user model

```
public function securityquestion_user() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SecurityQuestion::class', 'securityquestion_user', 'question_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('question_id', 'user_id', 'answer');
}
```

because your first option is correct except it!!

Comment: I have use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; at the top, so it's working. The belongToMany you wrote is wrong. First of all you are typing 'App\SecurityQuestion' as a string ( having the quotes ), also theres no need to specify App\ because I have  use App\SecurityQustion; at the top of the file.

Comment: okay! I don't know that you have imported it! but I have implemented it in my project it is working properly! Have you given relationship properly? Can you recheck check it!

Answer (score 0):

Try by using hasMany instead of belongsToMany in user model

```
public function securityquestion_user() {
  return $this->hasMany (SecurityQuestion::class, 'securityquestion_user', 'question_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('question_id', 'user_id', 'answer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, withPivot function expects one parameter: array or string.

```
public function securityquestion_user() {
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany(SecurityQuestion::class, 'securityquestion_user', 'question_id', 'user_id')
        ->withPivot(['question_id', 'user_id', 'answer']);
}
```

And 'question_id' and 'user_id' are not necessary to be in withPivot function, since they are the foreign keys.

Comment: withPivot function expects array|mixed, ie one array with string or many string arguments